# Retain pandas dtype 'category' when using parquet file

Tags: python, pandas, parquet

I am using parquet to store pandas dataframes, and would like to keep the dtype of columns.
However It sometimes ins't working:
here is the example code:

```py
import pandas as pd 
import numpy as np

df = pd.DataFrame({
    'a': [pd.NA, 'a', 'b', 'c'], 
    'b': [1,2,3,pd.NA] # dataframe has type pd.NA in it. 
})

df['b'] = df['b'].astype("category")
df['a'] = df['a'].astype("category") # with this columsn works 

print ("dtype before parquet write/read: ", df.dtypes, sep='\n')
df.to_parquet('trial.parquet.gzip',
              compression='gzip')


df = pd.read_parquet('trial.parquet.gzip')
print ("dtype after parquet write/read:", df.dtypes, sep='\n')

**OUT**: 
dtype before parquet write/read: 
a    category
b    category
dtype: object
dtype before parquet write/read:
a    category
b     float64
dtype: object
```